# Comparison between two tables inSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, comparison, sql-query-store

I want to know which "type" doesn't exist in snapshot table, but always got error on this:-

```
Select  * FROM 
     (Select type from snapshot) AS A where date = CURDATE())
    LEFT JOIN
     (Select type from register) AS B
ON A.type=B.type
WHERE B.type IS NULL
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Your first where is in the wrong place.

Comment: where should I put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT a.type 
  FROM snapshot a
  LEFT 
  JOIN register b
    ON b.type = a.type
 WHERE a.date = CURDATE()
   AND b.type IS NULL
```

Comment: It's also a good deal more sensible than the accepted answer :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
In Standard SQL Syntax:

Select  * FROM 
     (Select type from snapshot where date = CURDATE())AS A 
    LEFT JOIN
     (Select type from register) AS B
ON A.type=B.type
WHERE B.type IS NULL
```

Comment: your are Welcome